# Should I enquire about a newly announced PhD position while waiting the outcome of a previous application with the same PI?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, funding

I am considering pursuing my PhD with a particular PI who had a studentship available in their lab focusing on antibody drug conjugates (ADCs), and I applied for it, but received no answer yet. Recently, I discovered that the same PI has another position available in the broader field of therapeutics, which also comes with international funding. Both projects align with my goals. Should I take the initiative to email the PI and inquire about the second opportunity, or is this a risky move at this point

Comment: As a tip, please make sure your username is not your real name if you are concerned about what you are saying and, as a second tip, please work proofread your writing (such as punctuation). Also, I see no harm in setting a conversation (such as Zoom or phone call) to discuss positions with this professor.

Answer (score 0):

Showing interest on both positions should not hurt your chances of getting a position with the PI, it seems natural that you would be willing to work in either projects.

I would consider contacting the PI depending on the call deadline and the expected date to have an answer from your first application. For example, if the evaluation in the previous call is not finished before the deadline for the second position you can let the PI know that you will apply for the new position as well. On the other hand, if you receive a rejection letter from the first application you could also contact to understand if they encourage you to apply again or not.